# File "catalina.out" not being created/populated when using Tomcat 9.0.31 + Ubuntu 20.04 (content goes to the Ubuntu syslog instead)

Tags: java, tomcat9, rsyslog, debian-based, ubuntu-20.04

I have been using Tomcat for about 18 years. As far as I can remember, everything that I leave on the log with System.out.println() has been found inside the file "catalina.out" which has been nice. However, this seems to have changed.
I just migrated to Ubuntu 20.04 + Tomcat 9.0.31, and installed Tomcat doing a "sudo apt install tomcat9". Now I see that the file "catalina.out" never gets created, and that everything that had been sent there is now being sent to the Ubuntu/Linux/Debian log "syslog". I don't like that, I want to keep having a separate/dedicated log for Tomcat (which is something I check very often) and not havoing to search for it inside syslog (which is something I rarely inspect).

I have done some research, and this is what I have discovered (if I understood everything correctly):

- Tomcat now runs as a service inside something called "systemsd"
- For some reason, the people at Ubuntu/Debian/Linux decided that Tomcat's log should be found inside syslog, instead of staying independent inside "catalina.out". Why is that? I don't know and I don't like it!
- The other files inside /var/log/tomcat get created, including the "catalina.YYYY-MM-DD.log" files. But I dont' find my "System.out.println()" messages there, which has always been the case.
- I have found, however, that syslog tries to create and populate the "catalina.out" file as well, since I have found an error inside syslog that says something like "rsyslogd: file '/var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out': open error: Permission denied".
- I have also found a file "/etc/rsyslog.d/tomcat9.conf" which, indeed, seams to indicate syslog that the file "/var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out" must be populated. Which makes sense and should solve my needs.
- Considering the "Permission denied" error message, I started playing with the permissions (something that I really don't have much experience with). If I remember correctly, I created the file "catalina.out" manually, and the modified its properties so the owners are "tomcat/adm", since the "syslog" process/user seems to be inside the "adm" group. Restarted everything... and the "catalina.out" file got created and populated!!! So it seems that the main obstacle here is a lack of correct permissions so syslog can do what has been told and populate the "catalina.out" file. Did I get it right?
- However, when I delete all the log files (which I do every once in a while), the permissions that I assigned get lost and the file doesn't get created anymore.

What are we supposed to do to deal with this problem? Can/should we do something so the Tomcat log doesn't go to syslog? If not, and considering that it seems that syslog is trying to populate the "catalina.out" file as it has been told, what should we do to correct the permissions problem?

Thanks in advance!

Brian

Answer (score 1):

You have been using the STDOUT redirection into the web server (catalina) to debug applications.  I'm not a fan of that approach, but I've used it.  It is useful.

Since Tomcat is launched via systemd in this environment, systemd will redirect STDOUT (in any expected configuration) to a logging routine.  Since we are talking systemd, odds are that log is obtainable with a `journalctl` command.

Odds are you can get the log with `journalctl --unit=tomcat.service` but that is highly dependent on which operating system you are running, and how the config file contents (likely located in /usr/share/systemd.d/system/tomcat.service) as well as Tomcat's config is set up.